# Git does not detect repository

Tags: git, repository

A colleague of mine is working with git and after installing kdiff3 to use as a merge tool to solve a merge problem.

He doesn't know how but the git doesn't detect the repository but files seems to be there and correct /.git and .gitignore. I Google the problem and did not find an answer.

I have worked with git for 3 years and never saw anything like this. The last backup from local repository has like 2 months, unfortunately.

Comment: what do you mean with that `git  doesn't detect the repository`? what kind of error message do he get? What command is he trying to use?

Comment: are there files in `.git`? is it readable? can you `cd` into it?

Comment: Can it be accessed locally by git? Does "git fsck" report any problems?

Comment: we copy the files from an old .git to same place and solve the problem, I don't know how but it had the same commits. the git status comand for example only said not in a git repository. Thanks for the ideas